# Extract rows that starts with specific predefined string regex?

Tags: r, regex

Given:

```
"kuku": "kdfjsfgsljfddnlfdsf"
"bubu": "slfjsdjlkfndvsdl;nsdf;vlankvdfs;lkndkfv"
"title": "dflkbjvndjlvbdknbdlkbvjndlkfdnbdlkbjdnb"
"tutu": "svfrol"
"lala": "dbd4431"
"title": "dfvbdfv"
```

I want to extract all the rows starting with "title".

Please advise how can I do this (I am using R and want a regex).

I am trying this:

```
(["'])(title)\1:
```

and trying to play with it.

Comment: Please post reproducible example using `dput`

Comment: The input is just text file @RonakShah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to read the text file as dataframe in R

```
df <- read.table(text = '"kuku": "kdfjsfgsljfddnlfdsf"
       "bubu": "slfjsdjlkfndvsdl;nsdf;vlankvdfs;lkndkfv"
       "title": "dflkbjvndjlvbdknbdlkbvjndlkfdnbdlkbjdnb"
       "tutu": "svfrol"
       "lala": "dbd4431"
       "title": "dfvbdfv"', sep = ":", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, strip.white = TRUE)
```

and then select rows which has first column starting with `"title"`

```
df[grepl("^title", df$V1), ]

#     V1                                      V2
#3 title dflkbjvndjlvbdknbdlkbvjndlkfdnbdlkbjdnb
#6 title                                 dfvbdfv
```

If you want it as original string and not different columns then you can `paste` them back

```
do.call(paste, c(df[grepl("^title", df$V1), ], sep = ":"))
#[1] "title:dflkbjvndjlvbdknbdlkbvjndlkfdnbdlkbjdnb" "title:dfvbdfv"
```

Comment: Very elegant solution!

Comment: Please advise where the sep came from? I didn't see it in the c() documentation?
I do understand what you are doing here but this last point.

Comment: @SteveS that's an argument for `paste` so that we get two strings separated by `:`.

Comment: But you've put it inside c() or it's a typo?

Comment: yes, In `do.call` any additional arguments to the function which you are running can be passed in `c()`. Similar to `sep`, you can also do it with `collapse` like `do.call(paste, c(df[grepl("^title", df$V1), ], collapse = ":"))`

Comment: Where it's written? Any documentation?

Comment: it's written under `?do.call` Check `#Examples` section `## if we already have a list (e.g., a data frame)
## we need c() to add further arguments`

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like:

```
^"title":.*$
```

With your input using https://regex101.com it looks like this:

[image]

Explanation:

`^` means start of line

`"title":` is just take literally

`.` means an arbitrary character

`*` means it can happen zero or more times

`$` means end of line

Comment: . means an arbitrary character and * that the arbitrary character can happen  zero or more times

Comment: I have tried without ^ and it worked...maybe Atom doesn't recognize it